# Insert Dynamic Subtotal Formulas with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic

I wrote a code which insert some formulas into the worksheet depending on the length of code of the item.

I want it more dynamic and remove all "d" "e" like references in the Range formulas. The dynamic formula shall be according to the Last Column of the Range "Budget".

Thank you for your support.

```
Sub Macro1() 
Dim LR, LastColumn, TotalColumn As Long
Dim Kirilim1, Kirilim2, Kirilim3, ColumnNumberFromTotal As Integer
Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim ColumnLettersFromTotal As String
LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Range("Budget").Columns.Count
Set FoundCell = Cells.Find(What:="TOTAL", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
         :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                    False)
ColumnLettersFromTotal = Split(FoundCell.Address, "$")(1)
ColumnNumberFromTotal = Split(FoundCell.Address, "$")(2)

LR = (Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
Kirilim1 = LR
Kirilim2 = LR
Kirilim3 = LR

For i = LR To 1 Step -1



If Range("B" & i).Value = 8 Then

    Range("d" & i).Value = "=SUM(RC[1]:RC[" & (TotalColumn - ColumnNumberFromTotal + 1) & "])"

    Kirilim2 = Kirilim2 - 1
End If
        
If Range("B" & i).Value = 5 Then

    Range("d" & i).Value = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R" & Kirilim2 + 1 & "C:R" & Kirilim3 & "C)"
    Range("e" & i).Value = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R" & Kirilim2 + 1 & "C:R" & Kirilim3 & "C)"
    Range("f" & i).Value = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R" & Kirilim2 + 1 & "C:R" & Kirilim3 & "C)"
    Range("g" & i).Value = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R" & Kirilim2 + 1 & "C:R" & Kirilim3 & "C)"
    Range("h" & i).Value = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R" & Kirilim2 + 1 & "C:R" & Kirilim3 & "C)"
    Range("i" & i).Value = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R" & Kirilim2 + 1 & "C:R" & Kirilim3 & "C)"
    Range("j" & i).Value = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R" & Kirilim2 + 1 & "C:R" & Kirilim3 & "C)"
    
    
    Kirilim3 = Kirilim2
    Kirilim2 = Kirilim2 - 1
End If

If Range("B" & i).Value = 2 Then


Range("d" & i).Value = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R" & Kirilim2 + 1 & "C:R" & Kirilim1 + 1 & "C)"
Range("e" & i).Value = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R" & Kirilim2 + 1 & "C:R" & Kirilim1 + 1 & "C)"
Range("f" & i).Value = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R" & Kirilim2 + 1 & "C:R" & Kirilim1 + 1 & "C)"
Range("g" & i).Value = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R" & Kirilim2 + 1 & "C:R" & Kirilim1 + 1 & "C)"
Range("h" & i).Value = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R" & Kirilim2 + 1 & "C:R" & Kirilim1 + 1 & "C)"
Range("i" & i).Value = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R" & Kirilim2 + 1 & "C:R" & Kirilim1 + 1 & "C)"
Range("j" & i).Value = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R" & Kirilim2 + 1 & "C:R" & Kirilim1 + 1 & "C)"

                  
    Kirilim3 = i - 1
    Kirilim2 = i - 1
    Kirilim1 = i - 1

End If

Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the dynamic code and sample file for future references...

```
Sub AutoSubtotal()
Dim LR, LastColumn As Long
Dim Kirilim1, Kirilim2, Kirilim3, RowNumberFromTotal, ColumnNumberFromTotal As Integer
Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim ColumnLettersFromTotal As String
LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Range("Budget").Columns.Count
Set FoundCell = Cells.Find(What:="TOTAL", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
         :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                    False)
ColumnLettersFromTotal = Split(FoundCell.Address, "$")(1)
RowNumberFromTotal = Split(FoundCell.Address, "$")(2)
ColumnNumberFromTotal = FoundCell.Column
LR = (Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
Kirilim1 = LR
Kirilim2 = LR
Kirilim3 = LR

For i = LR To 1 Step -1



If Len(Range("A" & i).Value) = 8 Then

    Range(ColumnLettersFromTotal & i).Value = "=SUM(RC[1]:RC[" & (LastColumn - ColumnNumberFromTotal) & "])"

    Kirilim2 = Kirilim2 - 1
End If
        
If Len(Range("A" & i).Value) = 5 Then
    
    For j = 0 To (LastColumn - ColumnNumberFromTotal)
    
        Cells(i, ColumnNumberFromTotal + j).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R" & Kirilim2 + 1 & "C:R" & Kirilim3 & "C)"
    
    Next j
    
    Kirilim3 = Kirilim2
    Kirilim2 = Kirilim2 - 1
End If

If Len(Range("A" & i).Value) = 2 Then

For j = 0 To (LastColumn - ColumnNumberFromTotal)
    
    Cells(i, ColumnNumberFromTotal + j).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R" & Kirilim2 + 1 & "C:R" & Kirilim1 + 1 & "C)"

Next j
                  
    Kirilim3 = i - 1
    Kirilim2 = i - 1
    Kirilim1 = i - 1

End If

Next i


End Sub
```

[Sample File with the code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lLY-UkLwdIooWzUR2027Ez_pkJkThJtD/view?usp=sharing)